# O código não respeita os ifs

Tags: php, if

Olá, neste código quando executa ele não respeita os ifs, ele passa reto executando tudo. Por exemplo, caso apareça a mensagem "Esse usuário não existe" ele deveria simplesmente encerrar. mas também aparece a mensagem "Senha incorreta".

```
<?
include "conection.php";

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'"); 


while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $senha_db = $linha['senha'];
}

$cont = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if($cont == 0)
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Este usuario não existe')</script>";      
}
else
{
    if($senha_db != $senha)
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Senha incorreta')</script>";  
    }
    else
    {
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['login_usuario'] = $login;    
        $_SESSION['senha_usuario'] = $senha;

        header("Location: perfil.php"); 
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade você está atualizando a pagina quando você usa o META REFRESH.
Então quando o script para no segundo IF, ele recarrega a pagina d exibe o alerta. No entanto, a pagina volta a ser executada, mas desta vez não existe mais o $_POST, então o script cai no primeiro IF porque não havia usuário. E vai ficar assim.

Sugiro que deixe de usar o META REFRESH e passe a usar o próprio php:

Ou redirecionando pelo header:

```
header("location: sua_pagina.php");
```

Ou usando ifs para exibir o alerta JavaScript:

```
<script>
var _msg = '<?php echo condição ? "Mensagem verdadeira" : "mensagem falsa"; ?>';
alerta(_msg);
</script>
```